# Paraboloid geodesic (evaluate integral)

Tags: calculus, integration, differential-geometry, indefinite-integrals, calculus-of-variations

[Some context below, actual question at the end]

Wolfram MathWorld defines the [paraboloid](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParaboloidGeodesic.html) using the following parametrization ($u \geq 0$, $v \in [0,2\pi)$):

\begin{align}
x&=\sqrt{u}\cos{v} \\
y&=\sqrt{u}\sin{v} \\
z&=u
\end{align}

and the coefficients of the [first fundamental form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_fundamental_form) as

\begin{align}
P&=\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}\right)^2=1+\frac{1}{4u} \\[8pt]
Q&=\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}=0 \\[10pt]
R&=\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}\right)^2=u
\end{align}

Next, setting up the Euler-Lagrange equation is pretty straightforward:

\begin{equation}
\underbrace{\frac{\frac{\partial P}{\partial v}+2v\,'\frac{\partial Q}{\partial v}+v\,'^2\frac{\partial R}{\partial v}}{2\sqrt{P+2Qv\,'+Rv\,'^2}}}_{\displaystyle{=0}}-\frac{d}{du}\left(\frac{Q+Rv'}{\sqrt{P+2Qv\,'+Rv\,'^2}}\right)=0
\end{equation}

Plugging in $P$, $Q$ and $R$ from above, the equation will greatly simplify because of the vanishing term on the LHS, so we are left with

\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{du}\left(\frac{u\,v'(u)}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4u}+u\,v'(u)^2}}\right)=0
\end{equation}

Since the total derivative yields zero, the term in parentheses must be constant:

\begin{equation}
\frac{u\,v'(u)}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4u}+u\,v'(u)^2}}=C_1
\end{equation}

Rearrange:

\begin{align}
u\,v'(u)&=C_1\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4u}+u\,v'(u)^2} \\[8pt]
u^2\,v'(u)^2&=C_1\left(1+\frac{1}{4u}+u\,v'(u)^2\right) \\[8pt]
\end{align}
(Leave $C_1$ unsquared since its value is arbitrary anyway)

Eventually I arrive at
\begin{equation}
v(u)=\pm\int \sqrt{\frac{C_1+\frac{C_1}{4u}}{u^2-C_1 u}}du
\end{equation}

I was curious to see what Mathematica would come up with (solution for the positive branch):

```
Integrate[Sqrt[(C1 + C1/(4 u))/(u^2 - C1 u)], u,Assumptions -> u >= 0]
```

yields

\begin{gather*}
v(u)=\frac{u\sqrt{-C_1+u}\sqrt{\frac{C_1(1+4u)}{u^2(-C_1+u)}}\Bigg(2\sqrt{C_1}\sqrt{C_1(1+4 C_1)}\sqrt{\frac{1+4u}{1+4 C_1}}\text{arcsinh}\left(\frac{2\sqrt{C_1}\sqrt{-C_1+u}}{\sqrt{C_1(1+4 C_1)}}\right) }{C_1+4 C_1\,u} \\[8pt]
\frac{+\sqrt{C_1+4 C_1\,u}\,\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{-C_1+u}}{\sqrt{C_1+4 C_1\,u}}\right)\Bigg)}{C_1+4 C_1\,u} +C_2
\end{gather*}

Contrast this to the solution from [MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParaboloidGeodesic.html) (eq. 11):

\begin{equation}
u-c^2=u(1+4c^2)\sin^2\left(v-2c\ln\left(k\left(2\sqrt{u-c^2}+\sqrt{4u+1}\right)\right)\right)
\end{equation}

where $c$ and $k$ are the integration constants.

Apart from some more or less obvious simplifications to the Mathematica output, I was wondering how Weinstock came up with his solution. Any hints most welcome!

---

**Edit:**

Using the identities suggested by Rafa, I was able to get closer to the solution given by Weinstock. First, the output from Mathematica can be further simplified to

$$
v=2\sqrt{C_1}\text{arcsinh}\left(\frac{2\sqrt{-C_1+u}}{\sqrt{1+4 C_1}}\right)+\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{-C_1+u}}{\sqrt{C_1+4C_1u}}\right)+C_2
$$

Now, use the trig identities

\begin{align*}
\text{arcsinh}\left(\frac{2\sqrt{-C_1+u}}{\sqrt{1+4 C_1}}\right)=\ln\left(\frac{2\sqrt{-C_1+u}+\sqrt{4u+1}}{\sqrt{1+4C_1}}\right)
\end{align*}

and
\begin{align*}
\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{-C_1+u}}{\sqrt{C_1+4C_1u}}\right)=\arcsin\left(\sqrt{\frac{-C_1+u}{u(1+4C_1)}}\right)
\end{align*}

Therefore

\begin{align*}
v=2\sqrt{C_1}\ln\left(\frac{2\sqrt{-C_1+u}+\sqrt{4u+1}}{\sqrt{1+4C_1}}\right)+\arcsin\left(\sqrt{\frac{-C_1+u}{u(1+4C_1)}}\right)+C_2
\end{align*}

Since $C_2$ is arbitrary and $\log a+\log b=\log(a\,b)$:
\begin{align*}
v&=2\sqrt{C_1}\ln\left(\frac{2\sqrt{-C_1+u}+\sqrt{4u+1}}{\sqrt{1+4C_1}}\right)+\arcsin\left(\sqrt{\frac{-C_1+u}{u(1+4C_1)}}\right)+\ln C_2 \\[12pt]
v&=2\sqrt{C_1}\ln\left(C_2\,\frac{2\sqrt{-C_1+u}+\sqrt{4u+1}}{\sqrt{1+4C_1}}\right)+\arcsin\left(\sqrt{\frac{-C_1+u}{u(1+4C_1)}}\right)
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\arcsin\left(\sqrt{\frac{-C_1+u}{u(1+4C_1)}}\right)=v-2\sqrt{C_1}\ln\left(C_2\,\frac{2\sqrt{-C_1+u}+\sqrt{4u+1}}{\sqrt{1+4C_1}}\right)
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\frac{-C_1+u}{u(1+4C_1)}=\sin^2\left(v-2\sqrt{C_1}\ln\left(C_2\,\frac{2\sqrt{-C_1+u}+\sqrt{4u+1}}{\sqrt{1+4C_1}}\right)\right)
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
u-C_1=u(1+4C_1)\sin^2\left(v-2\sqrt{C_1}\ln\left(C_2\,\frac{2\sqrt{u-C_1}+\sqrt{4u+1}}{\sqrt{1+4C_1}}\right)\right)
\end{align*}

which is almost identical to the textbook solution:

\begin{equation}
u-c^2=u(1+4c^2)\sin^2\left(v-2c\ln\left(k\left(2\sqrt{u-c^2}+\sqrt{4u+1}\right)\right)\right)
\end{equation}

How can I get rid of the denominator $\sqrt{1+4C_1}$?

Comment: Simply drop it! The factor is constant, so we can redefine the second arbitrary constant as $C'_2=C_2/\sqrt{1+4C_1}$ and the factor is gone.

Comment: That did the trick, awesome!

Comment: The only difference left is $C_1$ vs. $c^2$ - is it permissible to simply replace $C_1$ with $C_1^2$? I hesitated to do so because $C_1$ also occurs as the argument of $sin$ and $ln$, both being transcendental non-linear functions. Would $C_1^2$ break the relationship LHS==RHS?

Comment: No problem, simply replace. In fact you didn't write the square on $C_1$ when rearranging the first integral. You were in fact working with $C_1^2$ all the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for a comment. It's cumbersome. Two identities can help.

Using the one [relating $\arctan$ and $\arcsin$:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Relationships_among_the_inverse_trigonometric_functions)

$\arctan\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{-C_1+u}}{\sqrt{C_1+4 C_1\,u}}\right)=\arcsin\left(\dfrac{\dfrac{\sqrt{-C_1+u}}{\sqrt{C_1+4 C_1\,u}}}{\sqrt{1+\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{-C_1+u}}{\sqrt{C_1+4 C_1\,u}}\right)^2}}\right)=$

$=\arcsin\left(\dfrac{\dfrac{\sqrt{-C_1+u}}{\sqrt{C_1+4 C_1\,u}}}{\sqrt{\dfrac{u+4C_1u}{C_1+4 C_1\,u}}}\right)=\arcsin\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{-C_1+u}{u(1+4C_1)}}\right)$

Compare with the rearranged from MathWorld

$\begin{equation}
\sqrt{\dfrac{u-c^2}{u(1+4c^2)}}=\sin\left(v-2c\ln\left(k\left(2\sqrt{u-c^2}+\sqrt{4u+1}\right)\right)\right)
\end{equation}$

Further, from an [identity with $\text{arcsinh}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_hyperbolic_functions#Inverse_hyperbolic_sine)

$\text{arcsinh}\left(\dfrac{2\sqrt{C_1}\sqrt{-C_1+u}}{\sqrt{C_1(1+4 C_1)}}\right)=\text{arcsinh}\left(\dfrac{2\sqrt{-C_1+u}}{\sqrt{1+4 C_1}}\right)=$

$=\ln\left(\dfrac{2\sqrt{-C_1+u}}{\sqrt{1+4 C_1}}+\sqrt{\left(\dfrac{2\sqrt{-C_1+u}}{\sqrt{1+4 C_1}}\right)^2+1}\right)=$

$=\ln\left(\dfrac{2\sqrt{-C_1+u}+\sqrt{4u+1}}{\sqrt{1+4 C_1}}\right)$

I think this can help.

Comment: Thank you, this almost did it - see my edit above. Still, there's a factor which I could not eliminate, any ideas?

Comment: See my comment below the question.